# Show/Hide Div That Isn't Nested

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you will see with the code, there is a list item with an anchor inside, the goal is to click the anchor and display the div that's also in the list item.

The issue my code faces is that if you click div information, it will hide it as well.  I understand why my code is failing, but not how to target `.inner-options` as it's own element.

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/hbhu6e16/)

```
<li class="options">
   <a href="#">Top Options</a>
   <div class="inner-options">
        First Inside Info
    </div>    
</li>
<li class="options">
   <a href="#">Middle Options</a>
   <div class="inner-options">
        Middle Inside Info
    </div>    
</li>
<li class="options">
   <a href="#">Bottom Options</a>
   <div class="inner-options">
        Bottom Inside Info
    </div>    
</li>

.inner-options {
    display: none;
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
}
li {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #EEE;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

$('.options').click(function () {
    var target = $(this).find('.inner-options');

    if ($(target).is(":hidden")) {
        $(target).show(300);
    } else {
        $(target).hide(300);
    }
});
```

My question is, what is the simplest function to use that will show and hide the `.inner-options` when **only** the appropriate anchor is clicked.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d33fn8uj/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rather bind the event to anchor element. that the event is only attached to anchor and not to div element:

```
$('.options a').click(function () {
  var target = $(this).next();
  target.toggle(300)
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chdvrqnr/)**

Comment: Interesting - I must have misread how .next() works.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Tushar: and why would he do that. what if he wraps them in different parents?? your solution will not work in that case as well.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Yes! Just said the case

Comment: @Tushar: it is better not to make assumptions for such thing. you will come up with thousands of them. and none will work for single solution provided for mentioned scenario.

Comment: @Tushar Yes - I was thinking the same thing.  There's many ways I could change this and have it work differently, but this scenario is unique - and the answer provided works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Apply `click` event on anchor tags and show the `sibling` having the `inner-options` class.

```
$('ul').on('click', 'a', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.inner-options').slideToggle(300);
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/hbhu6e16/2/

Comment: why the upvote for?? this does not toggle the div. simply shows it

Comment: What about duration??

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.options a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).closest('li').find('.inner-options');
    target.fadeToggle(300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Jquery toggle() is what you're looking for. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use `event.stopPropagation()`:

```
$('.options').click(function () {
   $(this).find('.inner-options').toggle(); // show/hide == .toggle();
});
$('.inner-options').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation(); // stop the event to bubble up in the dom tree.
});
```

As `$('.inner-options')` is the child of `$('.options')`, so any event bound on the `$('.options')` gets executed if `click` event happens on the child element `$('.inner-options')`.

So the solution is to stop the event to bubble up to the parent element by using `event.stopPropagation()`. So there has to be a click event bound on the `$('.inner-options')` and use it to stop the event to bubble up.